Не работает prettier от tailwind
добавил сначала команду для prettier, не работает, потом зашел в package.json и в писал там в раздел "scripts" >
"format":   "npx prettier ./src/index.html --write"
но всё равно ничего не работает, делал всё идеально по видео гайду но у автора как всегда всё хорошо, а у меня ничего не работает
